# cannot link to cvd.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have tried to run the program from the web for 3d camera, I use vc2010, opencv 2.4.7.

but when I run this program error is occur and said that :
`error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cvd.lib'`

I have look around in the opencv lib directories there is no cvd.lib.

where can I find this lib? or solve this issue?

Comment: you're right, there's no cvd.lib anymore ( there was one in opencv1.0, looong ago )  your project / makefile /code even might be just outdated.

Comment: Thank you, can I use it dan put it in my library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the link to cvd.lib download

https://www.assembla.com/code/AdidasAR/subversion/nodes/299/trunk/modules/lib/OpenCV/cvd.lib

!!!! Zope... :)